# Git change a project name without deleting and recreating project in repository

Tags: git, git-commit

I have a project in my git repository named outbount and since the name of the project should be changed to outbound (spelling mistake happened.), i changed it and tried to commit and push. But when i'm going to commit, it shows like the old project is deleted and new project is created. I just need to change the folder name. How can i do that? Please make me correct if i got the concepts wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So you have a repo of this structure:

```
ParentDir
  |- .git
  |- outbount
```

And you want to rename `outbount` to `outbound`. You need to tell Git that you want to rename the directory:

```
git mv outbount outbound
git commit -m "correct dir name typo"
```

That's it.